# What's the difference between row.names() and attributes$row.names?

Tags: r, dataframe

`row.names(iris)` returns a character vector:

```
> row.names(head(iris))
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6"
```

and `attributes(iris)$row.names` returns an integer vector:

```
> attributes(head(iris))$row.names
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I am surprised that these 2 functions do not return the same thing.  What's the difference between them?

Comment: take a look at the source code for `row.names.data.frame`. Perhaps the default rownames are stored as integers for the sake of performance, but you want `row.names(...)` to always return `character`, so you can rely on it.

Comment: More specifically in the source, `rownames <- function (x) as.character(attr(x, "row.names"))`

Comment: It's actually interesting because the row names of a data.frame *must* be character. But `iris` has the "default" row names. If you do a `dput(iris)` you can see that the row names are stored as `row.names = c(NA, -150L)` which means they haven't been assigned yet and R should just use the character versions of the indexes. There's a [special code branch](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/b7cab3540158e0fa6e3ec3019384905ba65d4801/src/main/attrib.c#L168) for this in the R source. If you were to set the row.names to anything other than the default/unassigned values, those should match.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde Sure. I didn't mean to imply `iris` was special. By default every new data.frame will have it's row names saved in the condensed/unassigned state. But if you ever want to index by row.name, you'll have to user a character vector. Otherwise numerical index are always positional.

Answer (score 1):

`row.names()` is a generic convenience function. As pointed out in the comments, a data frame is a list object with (at least) the attributes `"names"`, `"row.names"`, and `"class"`.

```r
> dput(data.frame("x" = c(1, 2, 3)))
structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 3)), .Names = "x", row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Inside `structure()`, variable names are passed to the argument `.Names` (not `names`).

In the base package, there are two methods for the generic function:

```r
> methods(row.names)
[1] row.names.data.frame row.names.default
```

The default method is
`function (x) if (!is.null(dim(x))) rownames(x)`
while the method for data frames (`row.names.data.frame`) is
`function (x) as.character(attr(x, "row.names"))`

If row names are not defined, row.names will be a vector with two elements, the first being `NA`, the second the *negative* number of rows (`nrow(iris)` is 150).

One important difference between using `row.names()` and `attributes()` is that the latter can break the data frame:

```r
> a <- b <- data.frame("x" = c("obs1" = 4, "obs2" = 6, "obs3" = -1))
> a
      x
obs1  4
obs2  6
obs3 -1
> row.names(a) <- NULL
> a
   x
1  4
2  6
3 -1
> attributes(b)$row.names <- NULL
> b
[1] x
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Since the attribute was completely removed in `b`, methods for `data.frame` won't work properly anymore:

```r
> str(b)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ x: num  4 6 -1
```