# dput's row.names are inconsistent with the ones returned from rownames(). Why?

Tags: r, dataframe

(Reproducible example added). Consider the following example:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3, 11,12,13), nrow = 2, ncol=3))
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  3 12
# 2  2 11 13
rownames(df) # "1" "2"
dput(df)
# structure(list(V1 = c(1, 2), V2 = c(3, 11), V3 = c(12, 13)), .Names = c("V1", 
# "V2", "V3"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

`dput`'s `row.names` (i.e., `NA`, `-2L`) are inconsistent with the ones returned from `rownames()` (i.e., `1`, `2`). Why?

PS1: Can someone add `dput` tag, I haven't enough reputation to do it (i.e., 1500 pts)?

PS2: The [What's the difference between row.names() and attributes$row.names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124199/whats-the-difference-between-row-names-and-attributesrow-names) has a similar problem. In the link, `row.names` and `$row.names` (both with dot) are used. In this  problem, however, `rownames` and `row.names` (dotless and dotted) appears. That said, the given link is helpful and solves the problem to great extend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between row.names() and attributes$row.names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124199/whats-the-difference-between-row-names-and-attributesrow-names)

Comment: see `?.set_row_names`.

Comment: @mt1022 `.set_row_names(as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3, 11,12,13), nrow = 2, ncol=3)))[[1]] # NA` So, now I understand where `NA` in `(NA, -2L)` comes from. Thanks.

Comment: No. That is not where the `NA` comes from. You should try `.set_row_names(nrow(df))` where `df` is your `data.frame` (i.e., `as.data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3, 11,12,13), nrow = 2, ncol=3))`). And you will get exactly `c(NA, -2L)`.

Comment: @mt1022, Yes, you are right: `.set_row_names(nrow(df)) # NA -2` simultaneously give both components (i.e., `NA -2`), mine gave only  `NA `!

Comment: See also `.row_names_info` and its `type` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row.names()` gives something for you or your program to read and understand (in a consistent and therefore predictable format).

Whereas, `dput()` gives `row.names=` in a format for `attributes()` to understand having received it from `structure()`, and it relates to the internal way the row names are stored in the data frame. `c(NA, -xL)` says they are automatically generated names from 1 to x.

Here is some interesting variations between `row.names()` and `dput()`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(list(a = 1:3, b = 3:1))
row.names(df1) # "1" "2" "3"
dput(df1) #  row.names=c(NA, -3L)

df2 <- df1[-2,]
row.names(df2) # "1" "3"
dput(df2) # row.names=c(1L, 3L)

df2 <- df1[-1,]
row.names(df2) # "2" "3"
dput(df2) # row.names=2:3

row.names(df1) <- 3:1
row.names(df1) # "3" "2" "1"
dput(df1) # row.names=c(3L,2L,1L)

row.names(df1) <- as.numeric(c(2,3,4))
row.names(df1) # "2" "3" "4"
dput(df1) # row.names=c("2","3","4"))
```

Only in the last test are they the same, and interestingly, even being a numeric vector forced again to be numeric, both return them as character vectors. For some reason `dput()` did not opt for `2:4`, but it did for `2:3` in the third test.

Comment: Thanks Erdogan for the edits, but on my machine the second last one dput() definitely gave row.names = 3:1 (and I just checked it again). So this behaviour is not even consistent between systems/versions or whatever, anyway both keep attributes() happy.

Comment: You gave very good info. I didn't think there would be a difference based on the systems/versions  on this issue. (For the interested: My one: Win10, 64-bit, Revolution R Enterprise32-bit 7.3.0 (I couldn't still digest the Microsoft's muck RevoREnt up), R version 3.1.1.)