# R: object with negative row.name value

Tags: r, row

I think I have the same issue with this: [What's the difference between row.names() and attributes$row.names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124199/whats-the-difference-between-row-names-and-attributesrow-names)

When I use `dput` now I get something like this:

```
-0.0120067403271522, -0.00712477902137182, -0.0105058179972997, 
-0.0115956365572667, -0.00507521571067687, -0.013870827853567, 
-0.0160501419238977, -0.00225243465241482, -0.0145865320678265, 
-0.00118232647592066, -0.0190385732141539, 0.0108223868283294, 
-0.0159300331503545, 0.0319315053338279, 0, 0.00315703437341087, 
0.0368045045454188, -0.0276264287281491, -0.0101235678857984, 
0.00486601316019395)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11834L))
```

I discovered this while I was trying to force define `rownames(var) <- c(list_of_row_names)`.

I get the error:

> Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names'
>   length`

The thing is this object has values inside it. Anyone can tell me how I can rewind/fix this?

From my understanding, this happened bc R didnt know row names when this object was created?

Comment: The issue is with what you are trying to assign to the row names. What is the class of that object? Does its length equal the number of rows? Don't concern yourself with the compact storage of the current row names.

Answer (score 0):

The length of that variable `list_of_row_names` does not match with the `nrow()` of the data frame

See an example given below:

```
df <- data.frame(1:5)
list_of_row_names <- letters[1:4]
rownames(df) <- list_of_row_names
```

> Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
>         invalid 'row.names' length

```
nrow(df)
#[1] 5

length(list_of_row_names)
# [1] 4
```